# Joomla 2.5: JError: Unable to load Database Driver: mysql

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, joomla

I've suddenly started receiving the message "JError: Unable to load Database Driver: mysql" when browsing to any page within a particular Joomla 2.5.x site. Other Joomla sites on the same server, that all utilise the same MySql instance, are unaffected. However, the other sites do use a different Apache vServer.

The environment is:

- Debian 7 on AWS
- Apache 2.2.22
- Linux kernel 3.2.0-4
- MySql 5.5.46

So far I've tried:

- Restarted MySql, Apache and the server itself.
- Double-checked the database, username, password and prefix vars in configuration.php. They're all correct.
- Checked DB user can access the DB by logging into phpMyAdmin using supplied details
- Created a new DB and restored a backup of the site DB, then pointed the site at the new DB.
- Searched any obvious errors in any obvious logs.

I'm not aware of any changes that would have triggered the error. As you might be able to tell, I'm not really that familiar with any of the components in the LAMP stack (I'm Windows, .NET, MSSQL kinda guy) so any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, both mysql.php and mysqli.php had gone missing from the /libraries/joomla/database/database directory.

After restoring them from a working instance, the error message goes away, but I'm left with other errors. I suspect I'll be hunting more mysteriously missing files.

Answer (score 0):

same pb here for a client, your web site is fully compromised with obfuscated code & so on. You'd better reinstall from scratch and secure it!!!! Check changed (models.php for instance) & new files (pathway.php)